# General solution of quadratic matrix equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be an invertable matrice, and let $B,C$ be any two matrices.

What is the general solution for the following matrice equation:

$AX^2+BX+C=0$?

If there is no general solution under these conditions, can someone give a counter example, i. e. finding a matrices $A, B, C$ such that there is no $X$ that  solves the equation, where $A$ is invertable of course.

Comment: You got voted to close because you asked a question without any context, any suggestions of what you tried, etc. Just 'here is a question, solve it for me please'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no solution in general, already for the equation $X^2+C=0$.

Take for example $C=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Proof. If there were a solution $X\in M_2(k)$, where $k$ is your favorite field, then we would have $X^4=C^2=0$. Hence $X$ is nilpotent, so $X^2=0$ (by Cayley-Hamilton for example), and thus $C=0$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to find the general solution for the given matrix quadratic equation.  However, if all matrices are $n \times n$ in size, it is possible to find a solution iteratively using a vector of unknowns (representing the entries of matrix $X$) of length $n^2$, and writing out (or evaluating) the $n^2$ $(i,j)$ elements of the quadratic equation, so that we end up with $n^2$ quadratic equations in $n^2$ variables.  I then used the well-known Newton-Raphson multivariate method to converge to a solution for arbitrary $A, B, C$, I used $2 \times 2 $ and $3 \times 3$ matrices, the method converged to a solution in less than 10 iterations.

As a demonstration, let

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 && -2 \\ 1 && 2 && 5 \\ 1 && 3 && 4 \end{bmatrix}$

$B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 2 && 3 \\-1 && -1 && 0 \\4 && 3 && 2 \end{bmatrix}$

$C = \begin{bmatrix} 2 && -5 && 1 \\ 1 && 1 && 1 \\ 2 && 3 && 2 \end{bmatrix}$

Then the described method converged in 9 iterations to the following solution:

$X = \begin{bmatrix} 0.32193625 && -1.04454087 && 0.147119861 \\
 -0.311847294 && -0.195352462 && - 0.278206133 \\
 -0.970090604 && 1.873941547 && -0.566145201 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Doubtful. There are lot of cases where there is no solution, so I cannot imagine how possibly your iterative method can converge to a solution.

Comment: Well.  I cannot prove that it will converge to a solution for any given choice of matrices $A, B, C$, however, with my arbitrary set choice of these matrices, the method described in my solution did actually converge to a solution, in both the $2 \times 2$ case and the $3 \times 3$ case.